# python open a serialized C# file

Tags: c#, python

I'm having an issue getting data out of a c# array serialized class with python. I have two files containing the classes. The first I am able to loop though the array and grab the public variables. However in the second file I see the class but am Unable to access any of the variables. It's been 10+ years since I used C# and have been beating my head against the computer. The only difference I can see is file1.bin uses String where file2.bin uses string. Any pointers would be mot helpful.

ironpython used to read .bin files.

```
from System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary import BinaryFormatter
from System.IO import FileStream, FileMode, FileAccess, FileShare
from System.Collections.Generic import *

def read(name):
    bformatter = BinaryFormatter()
    file_stream = FileStream(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,         FileShare.Read)
    res = bformatter.Deserialize(file_stream)
    file_stream.Close()
    return res

def write(name,data):
    bformatter = BinaryFormatter()
    stream = FileStream(name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite,   FileShare.ReadWrite)
    bformatter.Serialize(stream, data)
    stream.Close()

res = read('fiel2.bin')
for space in res:
   print dir(space)
```

File1.bin - (simplified) array of Resident - Can Access data

```
namespace RanchoCSharp
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Resident
    {
        public Resident()
        {
        }
        public Resident(String fName, String lName)
        {
            firstN = fName;
            lastN = lName;
        }
        //Invoice info
        public String firstN;
        public String lastN;
    }
}
```

file2.bin (simplified) Array of Resident Info Can't access data

```
namespace Rancho_Resident
{
    [Serializable]
    class ResidentInfo
    {
       public ResidentInfo()
        {
        }
        public string unit;
        public string space;
    }
}
```

**update**

After looking closer it appears that one class is public and the other is internal. However, I'm not sure how to access the internal class.

Comment: Fun problem :) String and string are the same thing. I would think that it is more likely different versions of .Net and that serialization looks a bit different now

Comment: Just noticed that file1.bin is a public class where file2.bin is not. Could that be the issue?

Comment: so is the problem now more along the lines that you cannot serialize the class at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, internal members are invisible to external assemblies including IronPython, but you can change that.

If you are running `ipy.exe`, start it by:

```
ipy.exe -X:PrivateBinding
```

If you are hosting the `IronPython` scripting engine, then add an option:

```
IDictionary<string, object> options = new Dictionary<string, object>();

options.Add("PrivateBinding", true);

ScriptEngine engine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine(options);
```